# Incorrect syntax near case

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to run this query, but I get incorrect syntax near case and mySum

```
Select 
    sum(sumTotal) as mySum 
from
    customertrans 
where 
    DateTime >= DATEPART(HOUR, '6:00')
    case when mySum >25 
    then update TopStatistics 
         set SumDelivery = mySum
```

Comment: "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for **professional and enthusiast** programmers".  You need to read up on [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure about your goals, but I think you need 2 steps:

```
Select sum(sumTotal) as mySum,
       case when sum(sumTotal)>25 then 'update' ELSE 'NoUpdate' END AS TopStatistics 
from customertrans 
where  DateTime >= DATEPART(HOUR, '6:00')
```

And then Update based on above output.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you but why my update doesnt work? update TopStatistics set sumretail= case when (Select sum(sumTotal) as mysum from customertrans where  DateTime >= DATEPART(HOUR, '6:00'))  > (select Top(1) SumRetail from TopStatistics)
 then mysum end
 i get incorrect syntax in mysum

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is not possible. This should work:

```
;with cte (mySum) as 
(
    Select sum(sumTotal) as mySumTopStatistics 
    from customertrans 
    where  DateTime >= DATEPART(HOUR, '6:00')

)
update TopStatistics
set SumDelivery = mySum
where <Search condition with cte table>
```